# How to add item to each tuple element of numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array A of shape (512, 512, 4)
Each element is a tuple: (r, g, b, a). It represents a 512x512 RGBA image.

I have a numpy array B of shape (512, 512, 3)
Each element is a tuple: (r, g, b). It represents a similar, RGB image.

I want to fast copy all the 'a' (alpha) values from each element of A into corresponding elements in B. (basically transferring the alpha channel).

resulting B shape would be (512, 512, 4).

How can I achieve this? The algorithm is based on fast pixel manipulation technique laid out [here](https://pytech-solution.blogspot.com/2018/02/fast-pixel-processing-with-opencv-and.html).

Code:

```
## . input_image is loaded using PIL/pillow
rgb_image = input_image
print(f"Image: {rgb_image}")
rgb_image_array = np.asarray(rgb_image) # convert to numpy array
print(f"Image Array Shape: {rgb_image_array.shape}")

gray_image = rgb_image.convert("L") # convert to grayscale
print(f"Gray image: {gray_image}")
gray_image_array = np.asarray(gray_image)
print(f"Gray image shape: {gray_image_array.shape}")

out_image_array = np.zeros(rgb_image_array.shape, rgb_image_array.dtype)
print(f"Gray image array shape: {out_image_array.shape}")

rows, cols, items = out_image_array.shape

# create lookup table for each gray value to new rgb value
LUT = []
for i in range(256):
    color = gray_to_rgb(i / 256.0, positions, colors)
    LUT.append(color)

LUT = np.array(LUT, dtype=np.uint8)

print(f"LUT shape: {LUT.shape}")

# get final output that uses lookup table technique.
# notice that at this point, we don't have the alpha channel
out_image_array = LUT[gray_image_array]
print(f"output image shape: {out_image_array.shape}")

# How do I get the alpha channel back from rgb_image_array into out_image_array
```

Output:

```
Image: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=512x512 at 0x7FDEF5F2F438>
Image Array Shape: (512, 512, 4)
Gray image: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=512x512 at 0x7FDEF5C25CF8>
Gray image shape: (512, 512)
Gray image array shape: (512, 512, 4)
LUT shape: (256, 3)
output image shape: (512, 512, 3)
```

Comment: Please add a minimal and verifiable example to your question plus the code that you've tried before.

Comment: @Kasramvd - thanks. I have no idea how to achieve it. I've added more explanation/example set.

Comment: So, is that a list of tuples? That minimal sample looks like so.

Comment: You tagged your Q as `numpy` but you don't use numpy arrays. So, are numpy array solutions acceptable?

Comment: @NilsWerner I updated the question with code. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using numpy slices:

```
import numpy as np

A = [[(1,1,1,4)], [(1,1,1,5)]]
B = [[(2,2,2)], [(3,3,3)]]

# A and B are tensors of order 3
A = np.array(A)  
B = np.array(B)


print("A=")
print(A)
print("B=")
print(B)

C = np.copy(A)

# assign along all 1st and 2nd dimensions, but only the first three elements of the third dimension
C[:,:,0:3] = B

print("C=")
print(C)
```

Output:

```
A=
[[[1 1 1 4]]

 [[1 1 1 5]]]
B=
[[[2 2 2]]

 [[3 3 3]]]
C=
[[[2 2 2 4]]

 [[3 3 3 5]]]
```

Comment: awesome. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's be careful about terminology

> I have a numpy array A of shape (512, 512, 4) Each element is a tuple: (r, g, b, a). It represents a 512x512 RGBA image.

If `A` has that shape, and has a numeric `dtype` (e.g. `np.int32`), then it has 512*512*4 elements.  The only way it can have a `tuple` element is if the `dtype` was object.  I suspect rather that you have a 512x512 image where each pixel is represented by 4 values.

```
A[0,0,:]
```

will be a (4,) shape array representing those 4 values (sometimes called channels) of one pixel.

```
A[:,:,0]
```

is the `r` value for the whole image.

If they really are 3d arrays, then @mocav's solution of copying columns (indexing on the last dimension) to a new array is the right one.

Another possibility is that they are structured 2d arrays with 4 and 3 fields respectively.  That would print (`str`) as tuples, though the `repr` print will make the compound `dtype` explicit.  But the solution will be similar - make a new array of the right shape and dtype (like `A`), and copy values by field name from `B` and `A`.  (I'll wait with details until you clarify the situation).

Comment: Updated the Q with code sample to better see the shapes.